# What is the POJO equivalent for this nested json?

Tags: java, json, pojo

There is a `json` response of a webservice :

```
{
  "data": {
            "token": "e3a5776e-bf55-4bf8-a6e3-008c849089da"
          },
  "error": null
}
```

I want to make a POJO for it ; what should be its structure ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming error is an Object, following is the POJO.

```
public class Data{
    public String token;
}

public class MainObj{
    public Data data;
    public Object error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many similar pojo implementations. I like to use inner classes for pojos with nested structure. So in this case we can have the following implementation

```
@Data
public class MyPojo {
    private DataPojo data;
    private String error;

    @Data
    public static class DataPojo {
        private String token;
    } 
}
```

Note that I am using [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) to not write manually getter and setter for the pojo:

> Project Lombok is a java library that automatically plugs into your editor and build tools, spicing up your java.
> Never write another getter or equals method again, with one annotation your class has a fully featured builder, Automate your logging variables, and much more.